# Using clang with codeblocks on Windows 7

Tags: c++, clang, codeblocks

I have managed to build clang on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 210 and now I like to use it with the codeblocks IDE. So I copied the clang executables into the mingw bin\ folder and updated the codeblock's compiler settings to use clang instead of gcc.

But when I compile the hello world example I get the following errors:

```
||=== clang_test, Debug ===|
obj\Debug\main.o:c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\system_error|447|undefined reference to `std::iostream_category()'|
obj\Debug\main.o:c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdexcept|170|undefined reference to `std::exception::exception(char const* const&)'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I guess I have to use clang's header files but how to I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*UPDATE*

MSYS2 packages are available for clang on 32-bit and 64-bit, and from what limited testing I did it seems to work quite well. The compiler can be used from outside the MSYS2 environment.

On how to install MSYS2, see [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/). Then just run

```
pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-clang
```

or

```
pacman -Sy mingw-w64-i686-clang
```

after updating MSYS2 to install Clang.

The patches used in that package (if you want to build LLVM/Clang yourself) are located [here](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-clang).

---

*old reply follows, slightly out of date*

If you want to use Clang on Windows for C++, your only option currently is to use (or build yourself) Clang with/for MinGW(-w64).

Lucky for you, I provide packages:

- [Clang 3.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.2-release/i686-w64-mingw32-clang-3.2-release-win32_rubenvb.7z/download)
- [GCC 4.6.3 dw2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-dw2-4.6-release/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-dw2-4.6.3-2-release-win32_rubenvb.7z/download)

Unzip both to the same directory and add `mingw32-dw2/bin` to `PATH`, or point Codeblocks to it. You will be limited to GCC 4.6's libstdc++. Clang 3.2's C++11 language support is fully functional though.

Note that Clang expects GCC style options, so I suggest modifying the Codeblocks GCC build process and replacing `g++` with `clang++` and `gcc` with `clang`.

Comment: This is awesome! I did as you said it works well for now. Note aside. Also the "Linker for dynamic libs:" needs to be set to clang++.exe. Great!!!

Comment: @chhenning That is correct. Glad I could help you to some Clang happiness!

Comment: @rubenvb do you know if Clang windows support is improving? I miss some libs from newer versions of libstdc++ (like the usage of to_string). And win64 support? =~~~~

By the way, your builds are great. I use the gcc 4.8 64 bits (works great), and your Clang build. (I'm using clang for compiling 32 bits, and gcc for 64.).

Hoping to have Clang 3.3 + stdc++4.8 with multilib(32bits/64bits) support. 

Your builds are the only straightforward way to use Clang on windows, the other ways are very painful right now =/

Comment: @AlessandroStamatto I think it comes down to resolving [this bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12684). I might look into building libstdc++ itself with Clang, which would bypass the ABI incompatibility, although I'm not sure how receptive the GCC build system is to this. Clang on Win64 will need a SEH implementation like the one in GCC 4.8 (or a better one, not relying on libgcc and only on msvcrt.dll), Note that `std::to_string` should work in the GCC 4.8 build you're using. If it's not, please contact the MinGW-w64 mailing list with the details.

Comment: can your pre-built release of clang 3.2 (only) be used with latest gcc I've installed already? or I need to get the gcc package along? . Thanks

Comment: @M3taSpl0it Currently, Clang needs a dw2 GCC 4.6. I bet any build qualifying for that will work, but I'm only sure about my build (of course). I am aware of a workaround that may make Clang work with newer GCCs, but I'd have to look into it (and I'm not finding the time `;-)`)

Answer (score 1):

clang does not support MSVC C++ ABI yet so C++ code cannot be compiled correctly.

Update: As of December 2014, clang does support MSVC except (heh) exceptions. To compile code you will have to do

```
clang-cl.exe /D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 foo.cpp
```

If you want to use clang.exe directly:

```
clang++ -target i686-pc-windows-msvc -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 foo.cpp -o foo.exe
```

etc.

For up to date status of MSVC support see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html

Comment: mhmm, that's disappointing. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: There is work going on this area, so things might change soon.

Comment: @cartman not to disappoint you, but work has been going on in this area since ... long. I've been eagerly awaiting decent Clang on Windows for more than two years `:(`. Closest I have is what's in my answer to this question.

Comment: @rubenvb it has been almost another 2 years now, any news on a more up-to-date method or newer packages?

Comment: @Garet: see my updated answer, it seems Clang has also made some progress for MinGW-w64 on 64-bit now, and you should be able to use newer versions of libstdc++ as well.

Answer (score 0):

My CodeBlocks build logs show command lines as

clang++.exe -fno-ms-compatibility -fno-use-cxa-atexit   -IC:\mingw\include\c++\4.7.0 -IC:\mingw\include\c++\4.7.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:\mingw\include\c++\4.7.0\backward -IC:\mingw\include  -c C:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.cpp -o C:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.o

ld.exe  -oC:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.exe C:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.o  -m i386pep -Bdynamic -Lc:\mingw\lib c:\mingw\lib\crt2.o c:\mingw\lib\crtbegin.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -LC:\Windows\SUA\opt\gcc64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-interix6\4.6.0 -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 c:\mingw\lib\crtend.o

and I can run the program. I've built Windows clang with VSExpress. If compilation or link is causing errors on your end, then comparing our command lines might help isolate the issue.